# Lua, local variables in a table

Tags: lua

Sorry in advance if this is an incorrect question. I'm fairly new to Lua and I'm not sure how to go about this. I want to access a variable stored in a table from a function variable. 
As far as I know there is no self-referencing tables before constructed.

An example would be this:

```
local bigTable = {
    a = {
        foo = 0,
        bar = function(y)
        print(foo) --Incorrect
        end
    }
}
```

What would be the best approach for this situation?

Comment: Define `function bigTable.a.bar(y) print(bigTable.a.foo) end` in the next statement after the `bigTable` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to create a table first, and append the keys to it:

```
local a = {}
a.foo = 0
a.bar = function()
    print(a.foo)
end
local bigTable = {
    a = a
}

bigTable.a.bar() -- prints 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```lua
local bigTable = {
   a = {
      foo = 0,
      bar = function(self, ...)
         print(self.foo)
      end,
   }
}

-- Somewhere else in the code...

bigTable.a.bar(bigTable.a) --> 0
-- or the shorter but (almost) equivalent form:
bigTable.a:bar() --> prints 0
```

I anticipate your next question will be "What does the `:` do?", and for that there's [lots of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blua%5D+colon) on SO already :)

---

Note that there's potential for a performance improvement here: if the above code gets called a lot, the `bar` method will be created again and again, so it could make sense to cache it; but that's pointless unless the surrounding code is already fast enough that this one allocation would have a noticeable impact on its runtime.

Comment: The line `bar = function bigTable.a:bar(...)` raises syntax error

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's because I had originally written it differently and then moved stuff around without double checking. Fixing it now ;)

Comment: The new version with `bar = bar(self, ...)` also gives syntax error

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm just dumb. Now it works, thanks for pointing out :)